# overriding django template raises TemplateSyntaxError

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm trying to reset the password_reset_email.html template in my django app by adding this file in `templates/registration/password_reset_email.html`:

```
{% load i18n %}{% autoescape off %}
{% blocktranslate %}You're receiving this email because you requested a password reset for your user account.{% endblocktranslate %}

{% translate "Please go to the following page and choose a new password:" %}
{% block reset_link %}
{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url 'password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}
{% endblock %}
{% translate 'Your username, in case you’ve forgotten:' %} {{ user.get_username }}

{% translate "Thanks for using our app!" %}

{% blocktranslate %}The team{% endblocktranslate %}

{% endautoescape %}
```

However it raises a TemplateSyntaxError:

> 'blocktranslate', expected 'endautoescape'. Did you forget to register
>   or load this tag?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which version of Django are you using?

Comment: I'm using v2.2.6

Comment: First, the `autoescape` and `endautoescape` can probably be removed. They don't expect any tags to be inbetween them anyway

Comment: I tried to remove them and got another error: `Invalid block tag on line 2: 'blocktranslate'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?`

Comment: This is why I asked what version you were using. There is no `blocktranslate` tag - it's named `blocktrans` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/translation/#blocktrans-template-tag

Comment: `{% translate %}` should be `{% trans %}`

Comment: aha, looks like the code I copied from the [master](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/registration/password_reset_email.html) branch isn't supported by 2.2.

Comment: I believe they are adding those tags in a future version and deprecating the old ones

Comment: Alright its working now. Thank you :)